# React js Axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm fairly to new to React and I can't seem to be able to successfully make a call to an external `API` using `Axios`.

The guidelines of the external `API` are:

Request (in case we know all the parameters)

```
{
  "service": "login",
  "username": "john",
  "password":"aitis",
  "appId": "2001",
  "COMPANY": "1000",
  "BRANCH": "1000",
  "MODULE": "0",
  "REFID": "1",
  ---- optional ---
  "LOGINDATE": "2017-12-31 13:59:59",
  "TIMEZONEOFFSET": -120
}
```

Response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "clientID": "Wj8Te8EqWghDM.........   .....wYGtzlyc1At%2bPrG8t"
}
```

My code is:

```
componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('http://...serverurl....', {
      params: {
        service: 'login',
        username: 'john',
        password: 'aitis',
        appID: '2001',
        company: '1000',
        branch: '1000',
        module: '0',
        refid: '1'
      },
       headers: {
         'accept': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'
       }
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

Instead of getting the clientID response I get this:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BPiF.png)

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
data:
success: false
errorcode: 0
error: "JSON Object must begin with "{" at character 2 of service=login&username=john&password=aitis&appID=2001&Company=1000&Branch=1000&Module=0&Refid=1 JSON Syntax Error : at charact↵
 error on character : 2"
__proto__: Object
status: 200
statusText: ""
...
```

Is something wrong with my call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are getting 200 code response so the request looks ok, look at the server in how to match requested params object

Comment: Are really those `headers` needed?

Comment: I've tried without them with the same result

Comment: your axios call cannot be correct, you are simply calling 'url', you need to actually replace that with the real URL, if it is saved in a url variable, it should be `${url}`

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have clarified that I replace 'url' with the real url

Answer (score 0):

If want to send a GET request with those params set those in URL

```js
const URL = `${baseURL}/url?service=login&username=jhon&password=aitis&appID=2001&company=1000&branch=1000&module=0&refid=1`;
axios.get(URL).then(response => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to use **axios.post** instead of axios.get.

Thank you all very much